# How to solve an incompatibility issue related with the manifest file and b2bi software?

Tags: java, manifest, b2b

I needed to implement a JMC project in Axway B2Bi software.I have followed the documentation, creating a component class, information class and a manifest file. I didn't find any sintax issue on my java code, however, it was not possible to implement the code. I think the problem might be related with the components of the manifest file that are not compatible with the b2bi conditions, but i have no idea how can I solve that.

my manifest file is similar to that:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.axway.xib.samples.Sorter
Container-Version: 2.6-UP2023-10
Component-Version: 11.0.21
Class-Path: ../lib/commons-lang3-3.14.0.jar ../lib/development-kit-api-1.3.0_R117682.jar ../lib/development-kit-runtime-1.3.0_R117682.jar ../lib/development-kit-simulator-1.3.0_R117682.jar ../lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar ../lib/commons-collections4-4.4.jar ../lib/commons-logging-1.3.0.jar
Build-Jdk: 11.0.21
```

According to the documentation [JMC](https://docs.axway.com/bundle/B2Bi_26_UP2023-10_DeveloperGuide_JMC_allOS_en/resource/B2Bi_IntegrationEngine_JMC_DeveloperGuide.pdf), the manifest file must look like that:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.axway.xib.samples.Sorter
Container-Version: x1.x2
Component-Version: y1.y2

Where:
 Main-Class is the name of the principle JMC class
 x1.x2 corresponds to the chosen API version
 y1.y2 corresponds to the actual component version you are currently developing
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add an empty line at the end of your manifest?
There should be an empty line at the end of the manifest. I usually add 2.

Just add it like this and give it a try.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.axway.xib.samples.Sorter
Container-Version: 3.7
Component-Version: 1.0
```

[Empty lines at the end of manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYZGb.png)

Are you referring to their sample Sorter code? If then; are you sure about the package name?
I have Their Sorter code in

```
package com.axway.xib.samples.processors
```

So the Main-Class should be like this. (For my sample version)

```
Main-Class: com.axway.xib.samples.processors.Sorter
```

Better to monitor trace logs when trying to compile.